# Problems with Window Previews with CompizConfig

Tags: compiz

i installed CompizConfig and activated Windows Preview, worked fine so far, also the windows previews, now i the window previews are shown anymore, in the menu of CompizConfig they are activated but work no longer. Already tried to reset the Standart-Profile in Profile and Backend. But makes no difference. Anybody has an advice what to do to fix it?

Comment: Hi,
I have the same problem. When I restart my machine it works. As soon as I do an Alt+Tab action to switch between windows, the preview disappears. Maybe you can confirm this?

UDATE:
It does not seem to be the Alt+Tab combination. If I log out and log in again previews work. But as mentioned above the preview does not work for minimized windows and if I select a window in the panel, by clicking, I need to click somewhere on the desktop first again for the preview to show.

Answer (score 2):

It often happened to me to think that it was not working because, in contrast to what happens in Microsoft Windows, this functionality only works for non-minimized windows. Are you sure this is not your case?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, can't answer via comment because my cookie was deleted.
Yes i think that's not the case. Perhaps it has something to do with a metacity theme i use although i acitvated to use the metacity compositing features via tweak-ubuntu.
Docky works for showing the preview windows, i can also tweak them for docky in size for example via compizconfig?

-seems that there are problems with the gnome panel, deleting and adding the windows overview to panel helps for some time, but then previewing is off again. Strange is that the preview works again, when you edit or move the panel. But they works not durable.